# sql select multiple refences to same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, foreign-keys

- I have a Table VOUCHER, with ID, USER_ID, APPROVED_ID...
- USER_ID and APPROVED_ID are indexes that reference the same key "ID" on another table USER
- USER has ID,NAME,SECLEVEL...
- Some users approve and some users make the voucher, if I want to print voucher with the ID, the user name and the approving user name. How could I make reference of to users to diferent values with a SELECT? I'm Trying with

  `SELECT VOUCHER.ID,VOUCHER.DESCRIPCION,USER.NAME AS NORMALUSER,USER.NAME AS APPROVINGUSER FROM VOUCHER JOIN USER ON VOUCHER.USER_ID=NORMALUSER`

But I don't know how to get the approving user's name on my code. I hope i'm explaining myselft well

Comment: `SELECT VOUCHER.ID,VOUCHER.DESCRIPCION,USER.NAME AS NORMALUSER,USER.NAME AS APPROVINGUSER FROM VOUCHER JOIN USER u ON VOUCHER.USER_ID=u.NORMALUSER  JOIN USER a ON VOUCHER.USER_ID=a.NORMALUSE` you can alias the table and join to it twice

Comment: As the answer(s) will say, you need two JOINs where you have one. When stuck, if you take the time to sketch the model, including the relationships it will be more obvious when you are missing a JOIN. Pencil and paper are underrated problem solving tools.

Comment: I was getting crazy with this tiny stuff thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `USER` table again using another join

```
SELECT 
    VOUCHER.ID,
    VOUCHER.DESCRIPCION,
    U1.NAME AS NORMALUSER,
    U2.NAME AS APPROVINGUSER 
FROM VOUCHER 
JOIN USER U1 ON VOUCHER.USER_ID=U1.NORMALUSER
JOIN USER U2 ON VOUCHER.USER_ID=U2.APPROVINGUSER
```

Comment: there is only a thing, please correct..
JOIN USER U1 ON VOUCHER.USER_ID=U1.NORMALUSER
JOIN USER U2 ON VOUCHER.USER_ID=U2.APPROVINGUSER 

USER_ID should not be compared with NORMALUSER as NORMALUSER is not an id, it's a name (should be VOUCHER.USER_ID=U1.ID)

Comment: I'm now noticing it doesn't filter the result by normal user, I mean i want to show only the vouchers made by 1 user, I'm currently working on it but if you can help that would be great

Comment: @aXul If you are having further problems then it may be worth asking another question